# Failed to install packages in R

Tags: r

I just started R. I am on a M1 BigSur Mac.

I have tried several packages, but I could not install anyone of them.

for example, `swirl`

```
> install.packages("swirl")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/swirl_2.4.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 108847 bytes (106 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 106 KB

* installing *source* package ‘swirl’ ...
** package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘swirl’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/swirl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/t6/qy2rcbdx0g9_fv98q1g48v_h0000gn/T/RtmpDAcI28/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

`tidyverse` it has been repeating the following output but it does not complete a proper installation.

```
* installing *source* package ‘cpp11’ ...
** package ‘cpp11’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (cpp11)
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c api.cpp -o api.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c date.cpp -o date.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c module.cpp -o module.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c rcpp_init.cpp -o rcpp_init.o
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o Rcpp.so api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

I tried `install.package('swirl', type='mac.binary')`.

It forces a successful installation but it gives the following error when I call `library("swirl")`:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: does adding `type='binary'`work? install.packages("swirl", type ="binary")

Comment: @sammy please see update. the error is too long for the comment.

Comment: Installing R via homebrew is the likely cause of these issues. Try installing R using the method suggested in the docs and on the [developer blog](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/11/02/will-r-work-on-apple-silicon/index.html) i.e. download and install the [ARM64 apple silicon binary](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/base/R-4.1.0-arm64.pkg) from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/, then install XQuartz, Xcode 12.4 and the experimental GNU Fortran 11 arm64 fork. Basically, just read the blog post